# Placing images (in a grid) next to the divs?

Tags: html, css

So here's my problem: I want to put six images next to those two divs, so they look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r2Xi.png Hope everyone gets the idea. Just a grid with six images next to these two panels with informations related to them.

```
            <body>
            <div id="pagewidth">
             <div id="wrapper">
              <div class="window">
               <div class="message">
                text
               </div>
              </div>
              <div class="window">
               <div class="message">
                text
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
            </body>
```

And here's style.css:

```
            #pagewidth {
                width: 70%;
                text-align: left;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .window {
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(117, 112, 107, 0.75);
                -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(117, 112, 107, 0.75);
                box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(117, 112, 107, 0.75);
                background-color: #D1D5D8;
                position: relative;
                width: 49%;
            }
            .message {
                margin: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
            }
```

Using float: messes up whole design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `flexbox`, I really like it. Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amwill/gowLta66/).

```
<div class="images-wrapper">
    <div class="images">
        <img alt="image 1" />
        <img alt="image 2" />
        <img alt="image 3" />
    </div>
    <div class="images">
        <img alt="image 4" />
        <img alt="image 5" />
        <img alt="image 6" />
    </div>
</div>

#pagewidth {
  display: flex;
}
#wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}
.images-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.images {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It works great, I got a question though. How to create a margin between the images that are next to eachother, and create a margin from the top of the website? That's how it looks right now: http://i.imgur.com/QsLBtGH.png

Comment: Did you add `margin` to `img` and `image-wrapper`? Or you could add padding to the element that wraps the divs and images

Comment: Nevermind, it works like a charm! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Use margin and left.right,top and bottom.
to Get more information  [click here](http://entertainment7899.blogspot.com/search/label/html)

Comment: no explanation, please don't just link, explain why it works - the link has no text explanation or even a great match with the question

Comment: Uh.. I don't quite understand.